# Can I set only vertical scrolling for QScroller? (PySide2)

Tags: python, pyside2

I have QScrollArea with inner widget and layout with vertically aligned images. Also QScroller for scrolling it by dragging. I have it working, but when you drag horizontally, it ignores other vertical mouse movement and not scrolling until you start dragging again. Can I fix it?

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
   
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.inner = QFrame()
        self.inner.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.inner)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        width = self.size().width()
        pages = convert_from_path('test_document1.pdf', 500, 'test_document1', poppler_path="poppler/bin", size=width*1.2)
        for index, page in enumerate(pages):
            page.save('test_document1/' + str(index) + '.jpg', 'JPEG')
            label = QLabel(self)
            pixmap = QPixmap('test_document1/' + str(index) + '.jpg')
            label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.layout.addWidget(label)
        # Scroll Area Properties
        self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setEnabled(False)
        self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_area.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.scroller = QScroller.scroller(self.scroll_area.viewport())
        self.scroller.grabGesture(self.scroll_area.viewport(), QScroller.LeftMouseButtonGesture)
        props = self.scroller.scrollerProperties()
        props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.FrameRate, QScrollerProperties.Fps60)
        props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.DecelerationFactor, 1)
        props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.DragVelocitySmoothingFactor, 0.4)
        props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.OvershootScrollTime, 0.4)
        props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.MaximumClickThroughVelocity, 0)
        props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.MinimumVelocity, 0.15)
        props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.MaximumVelocity, 0.6)
        props.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties.AcceleratingFlickMaximumTime, 0.3)
        self.scroller.setScrollerProperties(props)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the Qt Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Create and show the form
    window = MainWindow()
    # Run the main Qt loop
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: why wont you use `QPdfDocument`? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpdfdocument.html

Comment: Cant reproduce the problem. you also set `self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setEnabled(False)`  and that basically removed the `horizontalScrollBar` .

Comment: See if this works for you https://github.com/nrbnlulu/Qt-answers/tree/master/Qscroller

Comment: I will try QPdfDocument. Also I tried line you mentioned, the problem still persists. I will try to describe it more accurately:
When you click on QScrollArea and move mouse vertically, it scrolls normally even if you move it horizontally after that (without releasing mouse button). But when you click it and move mouse horizontally from the start, scroll won't happen even if you move it vertically after that. From user perspective it feels like it's just doesn't work half of the time

Comment: I don't get it, you want to scroll and drag at the same time?

Comment: No, I want it to always scrolling no matter which direction mouse is moving. One thing I noticed, problem only appear when there's no space to scroll horizontally. Anyway, thanks for sharing more clean code, I'm quite new with Qt as you can see :)